# MSVC2010: Why does my C++ Win32 project require a target .Net framework?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, unmanaged

I've specifically avoided using the CLR/managed project and yet it still asks me for a target framework.

[image: http://s23.postimg.org/gxzh5gqkr/Untitled.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a project like this in VS 2012 and the same thing was asked for. **I just ignored it** and there is no dependency on the .net Framework as far as I can see in the created solution.

Looks like a UI issue but only.

Answer (score -1):

There are different versions of .NET framework and the platforms they supports vary.

Don't quote me on this, but I believe I saw somewhere that the newest .NET frameworks don't support Windows XP.

If this is the case, there is a lot of reason to let you choose the target platform.

Comment: But the OP is saying that they doesn't want the framework - they want an unmanaged project.

Comment: In that case, I have no idea.